# Add silence between audio files while concatenating ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, node.js

I am using this command to concatenate my audio files:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mp3|2.mp3|0.mp3" -y output.mp3
```

but I cant figure out a way to add delay while adding files. I want something like:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mp3|2.mp3|silence=0.3s|0.mp3" -y output.mp3
```

Please help me solve the issue. Also sorry if I asked something dumb, becuase I am new to ffmpeg.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Create a short silent MP3 and then insert it as needed.